# ActiveRecord alternatives to limit due to performance issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am experiencing performance issues when using `limit` on thousands of records.

Are there any alternatives too `limit` that active record provides or workarounds?

My query is `Spot.where(<where_conditions>).limit(20)`

Some solutions I have thought about;

- Using a `where` clause to limit the records instead `where("created_at > ? and created_at < ?", 10.days.ago, 10.days.ago)`
- Pluck the `ids` from the main `where` query and then make an additional query to take the top 20 `ids = where(<where_conditions>).order('created_at ASC').pluck(:id)` then `where(id: ids.take(20)).order('created_at ASC')`. The concern there would be memory usage.

Comment: The `.limit` chain method actually translates into sql `LIMIT`, so if you are having performance issues, you might need to see what's the issue on the database level.

Comment: Use `.explain` instead to check whats actually taking that long. I doubt using `WHERE (subquery)` is going to be faster than just applying a limit to the query. `where(id: ids)` is actually worse since you're doing an extra query which has to make to the DB and back.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your `where_condition`:

- All columns in `where_condition` `indexed`? Did them `indexed` in right order as in `where_condition`?
- If you did not index all columns in `where_condition`. You can use `deferred_join` to improve performance

Comment: Could also use clustered indexes